# Convert np.array of type float64 to type uint8 scaling values

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I have a particular np.array *data* which represents a particular grayscale image.
I need to use SimpleBlobDetector() that unfortunately only accepts 8bit images, so I need to convert this image, obviously having a quality-loss.

I've already tried:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
[...]
data = data / data.max() #normalizes data in range 0 - 255
data = 255 * data
img = data.astype(np.uint8)
cv2.imshow("Window", img)
```

But *cv2.imshow* is not giving the image as expected, but with strange distortion...

In the end, I only need to convert a np.float64 to np.uint8 scaling all the values and truncating the rest, eg. 65535 becomes 255, 65534 becomes 254 and so on.... Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: What strange distortion is happening?  To me the normalization code seems fine.  Is the type of `data` `np.float64`?  Also, converting 65535 to 255 to me seems that your expected input type is `np.uint16`, not `np.float64`.

Comment: The image appears to have a sort of granularity, for example the black background becomes gray and unconstant (???).
Do you have any alternative suggestions?

Comment: I'd recommend dividing the image by the largest value experienced by that type, not the largest value in the image.  I've written an answer.  Let me know if it works.

Comment: I divided by data.max() also to normalize the values in the range 0-1

Answer (score 80, accepted):

A better way to normalize your image is to take each value and divide by the largest value experienced by the data type.  This ensures that images that have a small dynamic range in your image remain small and they're not inadvertently normalized so that they become gray.  For example, if your image had a dynamic range of `[0-2]`, the code right now would scale that to have intensities of `[0, 128, 255]`.  You want these to remain small after converting to `np.uint8`.

Therefore, divide every value by the largest value possible by the image **type**, not the actual image itself.  You would then scale this by 255 to produced the normalized result.  Use [`numpy.iinfo`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.iinfo.html) and provide it the type (`dtype`) of the image and you will obtain a structure of information for that type.  You would then access the `max` field from this structure to determine the maximum value.

So with the above, do the following modifications to your code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
[...]
info = np.iinfo(data.dtype) # Get the information of the incoming image type
data = data.astype(np.float64) / info.max # normalize the data to 0 - 1
data = 255 * data # Now scale by 255
img = data.astype(np.uint8)
cv2.imshow("Window", img)
```

Note that I've additionally converted the image into `np.float64` in case the incoming data type is not so and to maintain floating-point precision when doing the division.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. In your code appears to be *info.max* and not *info.max()* (that is not callable).
The code is working.

Comment: @Schneems.  The proposed change you made is incorrect.  It should be `info.max`.  `info.max` is a constant, not a function.  Please leave it alone.

Comment: Ahh, sorry. I see that now. I think @decadenza and I were both calling .max() on the image itself, which is a function. Also worth noting that there is a cv2 function cv2.normalize.

Comment: A small remark as I see astype used everywhere. "You should never use astype on an image, because it violates these assumptions about the dtype range". from http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/user_guide/data_types.html

Comment: @rayryeng For me `np.iinfo(data.dtype)` gives this error: `ValueError: Invalid integer data type.`.  `data` is just an float64 numpy array, correct?

Comment: @holastello `data` needs to be an integer type prior to conversion. If it's already a floating point array, this method won't work.

Comment: This should probably be scaled by 256. **astype(np.uint8)** rounds the data array down to range [0, 255].

Comment: Note that the call should be to `np.iinfo` rather than `np.info`. If you have a reputation of at least 2k, kindly revert the change introduced in revision 6.

Comment: @FilipBártek Thank you for the spot. I was unaware someone edited this. I've changed it back and I'm going to leave a message to the person who edited it and give him a piece of my mind.

Comment: @ncica Your edit two months ago was incorrect. Thankfully someone from the community noticed before I did and left me a comment. Don't edit an answer without leaving a comment ever again.

Comment: @FilipBártek BTW in the future, if you see an incorrect edit you can certainly propose an edit yourself and I will approve it.  It'll also give you a bit of reputation along the way :)

Comment: I think it should be np.finfo

Comment: @rayryeng "Don't edit an answer without leaving a comment ever again." That's a bit extreme.

Comment: @eric Yes I suppose it was, but when someone edits an answer of mine when it becomes factually incorrect, and other people could potentially use that incorrect answer, it bothers me a lot. I also think that something happened to me two years ago that really irked me, and it came out in this response. I suppose it was extreme, but I think a bit of decency where if someone edits an answer and leaves me a comment on what was edited, that goes a long way.

Comment: @rayryeng fair enough

Answer (score 26):

Considering that you are using OpenCV, the best way to convert between data types is to use `normalize` function.

`img_n = cv2.normalize(src=img, dst=None, alpha=0, beta=255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8U)`

However, if you don't want to use OpenCV, you can do this in numpy

```py
def convert(img, target_type_min, target_type_max, target_type):
    imin = img.min()
    imax = img.max()

    a = (target_type_max - target_type_min) / (imax - imin)
    b = target_type_max - a * imax
    new_img = (a * img + b).astype(target_type)
    return new_img
```

And then use it like this

`imgu8 = convert(img16u, 0, 255, np.uint8)`

This is based on the answer that I found on crossvalidated board in comments under this solution https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/70808/277040

Comment: I can confirm this works like a charm with OpenCV image data generated by Sobel/Canny/Laplacian, which contain float64 values and are thus not compatible with `QImage`, which I am using for displaying the results (it accept integer values only).

Answer (score 12):

you can use `skimage.img_as_ubyte(yourdata)` it will make you numpy array ranges from 0->255

```
from skimage import img_as_ubyte

img = img_as_ubyte(data)
cv2.imshow("Window", img)
```

Comment: yields ```images of type float must be between -1 and 1```

Comment: In which line ??