# OpenCV Python: Unable to save images from an array into a video

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to write a 3D np.array (from memory) into a video using opencv. Right now the code will run but nothing happens. I'm quite confused as to why this is not actually saving an MP4. Any ideas? These are grayscale images that I have stored in the arrays so there are no RGB values.

```
def convert_array_to_video(array, pathOut, fps):

    size = (array.shape[2], array.shape[1]) #size = (width, height)

    fourcc = cv.VideoWriter_fourcc('m', 'p', '4', 'v')
    out = cv.VideoWriter(pathOut, fourcc, fps, size, False)

    for i in range(array.shape[0]):
        # writing to a image array
        out.write(array[i])
    out.release()


def main():
    array = JTT_DXR_images_clip # shape = (232, 349, 888)
    pathOut = processed_image_directory + 'video.mp4'
    fps = 25.0
    convert_array_to_video(array, pathOut, fps)


if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

Here is the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-bdb5968613b8> in <module>
     20 
     21 if __name__== "__main__":
---> 22     main()
     23 
     24 

<ipython-input-36-bdb5968613b8> in main()
     16     pathOut = processed_image_directory + 'video.mp4'
     17     fps = 25.0
---> 18     convert_array_to_video(array, pathOut, fps)
     19 
     20 

<ipython-input-36-bdb5968613b8> in convert_array_to_video(array, pathOut, fps)
      8     for i in range(array.shape[0]):
      9         # writing to a image array
---> 10         out.write(array[i])
     11     out.release()
     12 

error: OpenCV(3.4.2) /opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/9523d527-1b9e-48e0-7ed0-a36adde286f0/volume/opencv-suite_1535558719691/work/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg.cpp:296: error: (-215:Assertion failed) image.depth() == 0 in function 'write'
```

I think the "(-215:Assertion failed) image.depth() == 0 in function 'write'" is the key to this problem but didn't find much luck online

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: It seems that array[i] has wrong dimensions. You can print its shape to check this

Comment: @user13044086 I printed the array and it has a shape of (349, 888) which is what is expected. Do you think the shape is incorrect in the frame dimension? (i.e. the number of images in the array)

Comment: Then you can check if data type of array is what `VideoWriter.write` expects. Most likely it should be uint8. You can also try to use named parameter isColor=False for VideoWriter to ensure that VideoWriter accepts grayscale images

Comment: That worked! The issue was the datatype. I converted the array of images to uint8 and the code ran as expected. I used Vasyl Vaskivskyi's solution from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46689428/convert-np-array-of-type-float64-to-type-uint8-scaling-values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up with using.

```
# convert array into video to be used by createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2

video_filename = processed_image_directory + 'video_full.mp4'


def convert_array_to_video(array, pathOut, fps):

    size = (array.shape[2], array.shape[1]) #size = (width, height)

    fourcc = cv.VideoWriter_fourcc('m', 'p', '4', 'v')
    out = cv.VideoWriter(pathOut, fourcc, fps, size, isColor=False)

    for i in range(array.shape[0]):
        # writing to a image array
        out.write(array[i])
    out.release()

    
def main():
    array = JTT_DXR_images_uint8
    pathOut = video_filename
    fps = 25.0
    convert_array_to_video(array, pathOut, fps)


if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```