# MNIST model does not predict the value correctly

Tags: python, tensorflow

I trained CNN for number prediction in the image and saved it. It predicts ok if I test it on the `x_test` data that is inner for the lib. But when I load my custom image - it does not predict well and I do not know why.

```
from tensorflow import keras
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import PIL

def normalize_image (img) :
    """
    Normalize image
    :param img: input image with range 0-255 int
    :return: normalized image (with range 0 - 1 float)
    """

    # taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46689428/convert-np-array-of-type-float64-to-type-uint8-scaling-values
    info = np.iinfo(img.dtype)
    norm_img = img.astype(np.float64) / info.max

    # tensorflow mnist use black background - so change bg from white to black
    for i in range(len(norm_img)):
        for j in range(len(norm_img[i])):
            norm_img[i][j] = abs(norm_img[i][j] - 1)

    return norm_img


# load my model
new_model = keras.models.load_model('numbers.model')

# image with number 4
img = PIL.Image.open('C:/Users/Horseman.mini/Desktop/4.png').convert('L').resize((28, 28), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
img = np.array(img)
img = normalize_image(img)

# create my custom tests list
my_tests = np.array([img])

# show the image which value I want to predict
plt.imshow(img, cmap="gray")
plt.show()
predictions = new_model.predict(my_tests)
print("Prediction value:", np.argmax(predictions[0])) # value that should be predicted
```

`My 4.png image as is`

[image]

`My 4.png image plotted after resizing and normalizing`

[image: number 4]

`output`

```
Prediction value: 1
```

Prediction is wrong so I thought dtypes are different :

`for comparing x_test data and my custom data lists`

```
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist  # mnist is a dataset of 28x28 images of handwritten digits and their labels
(x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()  # unpacks images to x_train/x_test and labels to y_train/y_test

x_train = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_train, axis=1)  # scales data between 0 and 1
x_test = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_test, axis=1)  # scales data between 0 and 1

print(x_test[0])
print(my_tests[0])
```

outputs are large, I will post one row for representing numberes and datatypes

```
# x_test[0]
 [0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
  0.         0.         0.         0.         0.33861822 0.450819
  0.32890224 0.02719964 0.         0.         0.         0.
  0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
  0.         0.         0.         0.        ] 

# my_tests[0]
 [0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
  0.         0.         0.00392157 0.         0.09803922 0.01960784
  0.         0.         0.         0.09019608 0.19607843 0.
  0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
  0.         0.         0.         0.        ]

# x_test[0].dtype
float64

# my_tests[0].dtype
float64
```

Cannot understand why it is not working. Datatype is the same, image arrays are uniformed from 0 to 1, image is correct, trained and custom image is 28x28 pixels (custom have this size after resizing), but something is wrong and I do not what exactly. If anyone could help me I'd be gratefil!

[Link to my model on github (numbers.model.rar)](https://github.com/AlexeyVolosnikov/tests)

Comment: Have you tried out any other images?

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal yes, I retrained the model and it has accuracy 0.99 (99%) and still does not always return me correct output. Almost always wrong (model in the link is old but new one is not better in my question)

Comment: I faced the same issue... I got it to work by adding more layers and increasing units/neurons. I had 4 Dense layers with 512, 256, 128 and 10 units each (10 neuron layer is output layer), compared to the previous 3 layers with 128, 128, 10 units. I do think it's overkill, but it works.