# Correct Thresholding for Canny algorithm, on physical variable

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, edge-detection, canny-operator

I'm trying to use Canny edge detection algorithm in python(newbie) for daily fields of temperature data on cartesian coordinates.
For example `Temperature= size(X,Y,time)`, 365 days of temperature data at 1-m intervals.

For this purpose, I want to use OpenCv Canny edge detection (cv2-Canny), because it is a built-in function, but a bit confused about how to apply the thresholds.

I want to detect edges, but with precise temperature gradient values.

To obtain the correct thresholds, my approach would be to calculate the temperature gradients, and get their range of probability density function (PDF) for 365-days.
For example, if most of the gradients are less than 0.25 Celsius/meter, than this would be my upper threshold. Following that Canny recommended an upper:lower ratio between 2:1 and 3:1, I would set my lower gradient to ~0.08 Celsius/meter. Or the lower could also be defined using the PDF distribution.

This is the point where I am confused. Do I need to convert/scale the temperature gradients (tempgrad) into "uint8" in the range of 0-255 as:

```
tempgrad_final= ((tempgrad - np.nanmin(tempgrad)) * (1/(np.nanmax(tempgrad) - np.nanmin(tempgrad)) *255)).astype('uint8')
```

or as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46689428/convert-np-array-of-type-float64-to-type-uint8-scaling-values)

and then apply the algorithm on temperature itself, as:

```
canny = cv2.Canny(temp, thresh_min, thresh_max, apertureSize=apertureSize, L2gradient=False)
```

where temp will be the temperature data, but thres_min and thres_max will be the temperature gradients scaled to 0-255?

Is this the correct approach? If not could someone please suggest how to set precise thresholds in cv2.Canny?
Thanks

I tried Canny algorithm with OpenCV, but the thresholds were very confusing and results changed dramatically depending on the thresholds.

Comment: Canny thresholds cannot be made to vary across an image

Comment: I do not understand what you mean here. Could you perhaps be more specific ?
I am not trying to set varying thresholds. Just a lower threshold and upper threshold. The only question is how do I correctly set them, so they correspond to a certain gradient value on the actual physical field.

Comment: I don't think you can, as Canny thresholds do not correspond to the values you're plotting. Perhaps this helps: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector#Double_threshold . What is your end goal? Sounds like a strange way to get to contour plots.

Comment: you might want to provide *data* people can work with. [mre] can be interpreted to mean that you provide something tangible for discussion, vs. textual description which isn't tangible. -- opencv's canny assumes that it's working on the "state", not the gradient map. it implicitly does a sobel or something. you would have to predict its internal result to figure out what kind of thresholds to set. -- all of that is separate from mapping physical values into an integer value range.

Comment: My endgoal is to calculate the gradient magnitude(e.g Sobel). I only need Canny, to give me the edges. But they need to correspond to the real world data. Otherwise, its just some image manipulation with no physical meaning.
Please see a real world example here:
https://www.mdpi.com/2072-4292/13/2/181
Here, they actually take a temperature field (in this case, in the ocean), and assign a Gradient-value of 0.1 Celsius/km (based on probability density distribution) as a threshold for the Canny algorithm. Perhaps this is more meaningful. This is the closest example I can provide.
Thanks

Comment: That's interesting, thanks. Looking at the paper, they have a justification for the higher threshold, but don't mention the lower one. The two Canny references within just say "thresholds employed are x and y", and that "different thresholds may need to be applied". Seems like you twist the knobs until you see what you want to see. I would normalise the image using `tempgrad_norm = cv2.normalize(src=tempgrad, dst=None, alpha=0, beta=255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8U)`, and scale your min and max threshold in the same way.

Comment: So if your data contains values in the range of [0.2, 0.6], and your thresholds are 0.3 and 0.4, the scaled thresholds would be 64 and 128.

Comment: Indeed, sounds like it is sort of a trial and error approximation. Thank you for the comment and answers.